# How to create Reflecting linerenderer with raycast?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity I have created cube and player. The player has LineRenderer component.The line hits the cube and stops. This is following code in player.

```
_lineRenderer.SetPosition(0,transform.position);
       RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit))
        {
             if (hit.collider)
             {
                 _lineRenderer.SetPosition(1,hit.point);
              /*   if(hit.collider){
                     Vector3 pos = Vector3.Reflect (hit.point - transform.position, hit.normal);
                     _lineRenderer.SetPosition(2,pos);
                     //lineRenderer.SetPosition(3, pos);
                 }*/
             }
        }
```

This works fine. But how can I reflect the line after hitting cube. As you can see in my code's comment I tried to reflect with `Vector3.Reflect`.But it did not work.If I run it shows me an error like**LineRenderer.SetPosition index out of bounds** How can I reflect line like in this image [image: ok]

Comment: What does it look like when YOU run it?

Comment: It shows me an error like "LineRenderer.SetPosition index out of bounds!"

Comment: OK, that's an issue with your line renderer setup, not the Reflect.  You haven't set the number of positions the Line Renderer uses correctly.

Comment: @Immersive why did you delete your answer? It solved my question with your last comment. I tried to use vector but I should use position

Comment: Because it didn't answer your actual question, only a different problem also in your code.  I have restored it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, your initial problem is not setting the correct number of points for the LineRenderer to use:

```
if (hit.collider)
{
     _lineRenderer.positionCount = 3;
     _lineRenderer.SetPosition(1,hit.point);
     // etc
}
else
    _lineRenderer.positionCount = 2; // No bounced ray
```

---

Also, `Reflect` returns a *direction* vector, but you're trying to use it as a position:

```
_lineRenderer.SetPosition(2,pos);
```

You need to apply the direction to an existing starting point.  Do this:

```
_lineRenderer.SetPosition(2, hit.point + pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that your LineRenderer does not provide enough space for setting a third point.

Unity's LineRenderer.SetPosition(...) does not manage the number of actually available points in a LineRenderer for you. You have to configure this manually before setting the points.
If you want a LineRenderer built from 3 points (player, reflection point, end of reflected ray) just use:

```
_lineRenderer.positionCount = 3; // tells the renderer it consists of 3 points
_lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, yourFirstPosition);
_lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, yourSecondPosition);
_lineRenderer.SetPosition(2, yourThirdPosition);
```

Comment: There are ways around needing to know the point count beforehand by building a List, but this suffices here.

Comment: No, even if you have a list you do know the point count. It's the count of your list in that case. But you can not set the line renderer to simply use "all available points", that is.

Comment: Ahh, I get you now. Your point is that we still need to tell the LineRenderer how many points it needs to manage before giving it the points. Agreed.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer to prevent misunderstanings.